# How do I return all visible text on a web page as a big, unparsed string?

Tags: c#

I am looking for a simple script that would basically do the equivalent of a user pressing Ctrl+A (select all) on a web page and then copying the text to the clipboard so I can pull it into a string from there.

The reason I want to emulate a user selecting all and then copy and pasting is because some pages are generated with Javascript and do not have the visible text in the HTML.

In any case, I am just looking for the raw unparsed text. I do not care if the spacing/line breaks are messed up, etc. I just want a quick and dirty snapshot of all the selectable text on the page into a string.

I have tried doing below as an example:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HAP.HtmlWeb web = new HAP.HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.
               Load(@"https://mywebsite");
            string str = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
            MessageBox.Show(str);
        }
```

but if the page has javascript it does not return the text displayed by it.

Comment: Share your code what you have implemented so far.

Comment: I did above just now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

Use this

```
doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

It will get you the whole HTML including JS and CSS. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery: `$(document).text()` or `$('body').text()`